# How to use annotate and KeyTextTransform and KeyTransform to extract first element of nested array?

Tags: django, postgresql, jsonb, django-annotate

I am using Django 2.2 and postgres

I have a jsonb field called `actions`

And this is test value

```
actions={
    "accept": [
        {
            "id": 123,  # some random action id
            "created": "{:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z}".format(datetime.now()),
            "user_id": 247,  # some random user id
        }
    ]
},
```

SO I want to use `values_list` and `annotate`. I do not know how to just get the `actions.accept.0.created`

### WHat I tried

`.annotate(first_accept=KeyTextTransform(0, KeyTextTransform("accept", "quotation__actions")))`

This fails. I get the error

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "accept"
LINE 1: ...te_type", ("sometable"."actions" #>> ARRAY['accept',0..
```

`.annotate(accept_actions=KeyTextTransform("accept", "quotation__actions"))`

This works but it gives me

`'[{"id": 123, "created": "2020-10-16T12:28:16.452071", "user_id": 247}]'` as a string.

I can subsequently parse that string yes, but I prefer to directly access the `created` of the first element of the array.

How do I do that?